# As divs não se ajustam quando abro um summary

Tags: html, css, html5

```css
.parallax2{
    height: 16vw;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: transparent;
    background-color: red;

}

#submete{
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 19vw;
    padding-right: 19vw;
    background: url(imgs/tech.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

#submetetext{
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding-top: 2vw;
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 3vw;
}

#submetetext h4{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

#submetetext h2{
    padding-top: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 2vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-indent: 0; 
}

#submetetext h3{
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    text-indent: 3vw;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="parallax.js-1.5.0\parallax.min.js"></script>
 
 <section id="submete">
        <div id="submetetext">
            
            <h2>Guião de Texto</h2>
            <h3>Directrizes de Submissão</h3>
                <p>Os autores devem enviar um documento em inglês, verificando cuidadosamente a gramática e a ortografia corretas, abordando uma ou várias das áreas ou tópicos da conferência</p>

                <p>Cada artigo deve indicar claramente a natureza da contribuição técnica / científica e os problemas, domínios ou ambientes a que é aplicável.</p>

                <p>Para facilitar o método de avaliação do papel em dupla ocultação, os autores são obrigados a produzir e fornecer o documento sem qualquer referência a nenhum dos autores, incluindo os detalhes pessoais dos autores, a seção de reconhecimento do documento e qualquer outra referência que possa divulgar o documento. identidade dos autores.</p>

                <p>Somente os documentos originais devem ser enviados. Os autores são aconselhados a ler as normas éticas do INSTICC em relação ao plágio e ao autoplagismo antes de enviar e devem certificar-se de que suas submissões não se sobrepõem substancialmente ao trabalho que foi publicado em outro lugar ou simultaneamente submetido a uma revista ou a outra conferência com os procedimentos. Os documentos que contenham qualquer forma de plágio serão rejeitados sem comentários.</p>
                
                <p>Todos os documentos devem ser enviados através da plataforma de apresentação on-line PRIMORIS e devem seguir as instruções e os modelos fornecidos nos documentos aqui, que também são os modelos para a submissão da câmera. Após a apresentação do documento ter sido concluída com sucesso, os autores receberão um e-mail de confirmação automático.Todos os trabalhos apresentados no local da conferência estarão disponíveis na Biblioteca Digital SCITEPRESS. É planejado publicar uma pequena lista de versões revisadas e estendidas de artigos apresentados com Springer em um livro da Série LNAI.</p>
            
            <h3>Processo de Revisão</h3>
                <p>Todas as revisões são baseadas em envios de artigos completos (não resumos) após um processo em dupla ocultação. Todos os artigos estão sujeitos a análise de plágio usando uma ferramenta de software antes da revisão.</p>
                
                <p>Todos os trabalhos regulares são revisados ??por pelo menos dois revisores, mas geralmente por três ou mais, e avaliado considerando: Relevância, Originalidade, Qualidade Técnica, Importância e Apresentação. Os revisores também são convidados a responder um grupo de perguntas que podem ajudar os autores a melhorar o papel.</p>
                
                <p>Finalmente, os revisores podem fornecer algumas observações de texto livre que foram entregues aos autores e também algumas observações privadas de texto livre, disponibilizadas apenas para a cadeira do programa. Avaliações conflitantes podem exigir a atribuição de um novo revisor. No final, as cadeiras do programa decidem. O autor tem um período de refutação, o que desencadeia um fluxo de trabalho envolvendo as cadeiras e os revisores, se necessário. Todas as réplicas são respondidas, mas as decisões são finais.</p>
            
                <p>Os documentos de posição seguem um processo semelhante, mas os critérios utilizados para a classificação são ligeiramente diferentes, a fim de explicar a natureza desses documentos, ou seja, idéias especulativas e / ou trabalhos em andamento ainda não totalmente validados.</p>
                
            <h3>Formatos de papel de conferência, incluindo sessões e workshops especiais</h3>

                <p>Os autores podem enviar seu trabalho sob a forma de um Documento Regular, representando pesquisa completa e validada, ou como Documento de Posição, retratando trabalhos em andamento ou uma opinião discutível sobre um problema.</p>
                
            <details><summary><h4>Papéis Regulares</h4></summary>
                
                <p><b>Envio:</b> Recomenda-se que os Documentos regulares sejam submetidos a revisão com cerca de 8 a 10 páginas, com o tamanho da fonte e o formato da página apropriados, incluindo referências, tabelas, gráficos, imagens e apêndices. As inscrições com menos de 4 páginas ou mais de 13 páginas serão automaticamente rejeitadas.</p>
                
                <p><b>Aceitação:</b> Após uma revisão de pares duplo-cega, os documentos periódicos qualificados podem ser aceitos como documentos completos ou papéis curtos.</p>
                
                <p><b>Apresentação:</b> os trabalhos regulares classificados como papéis completos recebem um espaço de 30 minutos para uma apresentação oral na conferência. Os papéis regulares classificados como Papéis curtos recebem um espaço de 20 minutos para uma apresentação oral ou atribuídos a um presente em uma sessão de cartazes. Os autores que receberam uma apresentação oral, completa ou curta, podem, no entanto, optar por apresentar uma Sessão de cartaz, em vez disso, se preferirem.</p>
                
                <p><b>Publicação:</b> os documentos regulares classificados como Papéis completos receberão um limite de 12 páginas nos Procedimentos da Conferência, enquanto os Documentos regulares classificados como Papéis Curtos têm um limite de 8 páginas. Se for absolutamente necessário, os autores podem aumentar o número total de páginas por um máximo de 4 páginas extras, por uma taxa adicional. O número total de páginas a considerar é o número obtido após o papel ter sido formatado corretamente de acordo com o modelo apropriado. Os Procedimentos da Conferência serão publicados sob um número ISBN pela SCITEPRESS e incluirão versões finais de todos os documentos aceitos, ajustados para satisfazer as recomendações dos revisores. Eles serão obtidos em suporte de papel e CD-Rom, e disponibilizados para consulta on-line na Biblioteca Digital SCITEPRESS. A publicação on-line é exclusiva de artigos que foram publicados e apresentados no evento.</p>
                
                <p><b>Indexação:</b> Os procedimentos serão submetidos ao Índice de Citação de Processos da Conferência da Thomson Reuters (CPCI / ISI), INSPEC, DBLP, EI (Elsevier Engineering Village Index) e Scopus para indexação.</p></details>
                
            <details><summary><h4>Papéis Posicionados</h4></summary>
                <p><b>Apresentação:</b> os documentos de posição devem ser submetidos para revisão com cerca de 6 ou 7 páginas, com o tamanho da fonte e o formato da página apropriados, incluindo referências, tabelas, gráficos, imagens e apêndices. As inscrições com menos de 4 páginas ou mais de 9 páginas serão automaticamente rejeitadas.</p>

                <p><b>Aceitação:</b> Após uma revisão de pares duplo-cega, os Documentos de Posição qualificados serão aceitos como Documentos Curtos.</p>

                <p><b>Apresentação:</b> os papéis de posição recebem um espaço de 20 minutos para uma apresentação oral ou atribuídos a um presente em uma sessão de cartazes. Os autores que receberam uma apresentação oral podem, no entanto, optar por apresentar uma Sessão de cartaz, em vez disso, se preferirem.</p>

                <p><b>Publicação:</b> os documentos de posição receberão um limite de 8 páginas nos Procedimentos da Conferência, que incluirão versões finais de todos os documentos aceitos, ajustados para satisfazer as recomendações dos revisores. Se for absolutamente necessário, os autores podem aumentar o número total de páginas por um máximo de 4 páginas extras, por uma taxa adicional. O número total de páginas a considerar é o número obtido após o papel ter sido formatado corretamente de acordo com o modelo apropriado. Os Procedimentos da Conferência serão publicados sob um número ISBN pela SCITEPRESS, em suporte de papel e CD-ROM, e disponibilizados para consulta on-line na Biblioteca Digital SCITEPRESS. A publicação on-line é exclusiva de artigos que foram publicados e apresentados no evento.</p>

                <p><b>Indexação:</b> Os procedimentos serão submetidos ao Índice de Citação de Processos da Conferência da Thomson Reuters (CPCI / ISI), INSPEC, DBLP, EI (Elsevier Engineering Village Index) e Scopus para indexação.</p></details>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <div class="parallax2" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="imgs\galeriaparalax.jpg">
        <h1 id="titulogaleria">Galeria</h1>
    </div>
```

Bom dia, estou a realizar um trabalho e ao abrir os meus  `summary` a informação fica sobreposta a uma `div` que eu tenho como parallax.

Como faço para a `div` se ajustar à abertura do `summary`?

Como podem ver o paragrafo galeria ajusta-se quando o summary abre, mas no meu projecto tenho um background na div com class parallax2 e essa imagem fica estatica, fazendo com que o texto da summary fique em cima da imagem. Eu quero que a imagem ande para baixo como o paragrafo galeria.

Antes de abrir o summary: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Depois de abrir o summary: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como pode ver a imagem ficou estatica e o texto Galeria ajustou-se ao summary: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boom bem vindo. Por favor inclua na sua pergunta todo o código que tem de HTML e CSS, assim fica mais fácil para te dar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: No Snippet que vc postou o Summary abre normal e empurra a Galeria para baixo. Teria como vc postar uma imagem do Erro na tela?

Comment: @hugocsl já postei as imagens

Answer (score 1):

Como o Parallax converte a `div` em fixa, essa `div` tende a não acompanhar o fluidez dos elementos quando eles são alterados de forma dinâmica. Porém, há uma forma de forçar o plugin a se readaptar, forçando a `div` a ir para baixo.

Considerando que o Parallax detecta eventos como `scroll` e `resize`, basta você adicionar um *listener* no `window` detectando o `click` e o `scroll` e disparando um *falso* `resize`, inserindo um simples código jQuery na página:

```
$(window).on("click scroll",function(){
   $(window).resize();
});
```

**Veja funcionando:**

```js
$(window).on("click scroll",function(){
   $(window).resize();
});
```

```css
.parallax2{
    height: 16vw;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: transparent;
    sbackground-color: red;

}

#submete{
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 19vw;
    padding-right: 19vw;
    background: url();
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

#submetetext{
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding-top: 2vw;
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 3vw;
}

#submetetext h4{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}

#submetetext h2{
    padding-top: 2vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 2vw;
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-indent: 0; 
}

#submetetext h3{
    font-size: 2.5vw;
    text-indent: 3vw;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/parallax.js/1.4.2/parallax.min.js"></script>
<section id="submete">
        <div id="submetetext">
            
            <h2>Guião de Texto</h2>
            <h3>Directrizes de Submissão</h3>
                <p>Os autores devem enviar um documento em inglês, verificando cuidadosamente a gramática e a ortografia corretas, abordando uma ou várias das áreas ou tópicos da conferência</p>

                <p>Cada artigo deve indicar claramente a natureza da contribuição técnica / científica e os problemas, domínios ou ambientes a que é aplicável.</p>

                <p>Para facilitar o método de avaliação do papel em dupla ocultação, os autores são obrigados a produzir e fornecer o documento sem qualquer referência a nenhum dos autores, incluindo os detalhes pessoais dos autores, a seção de reconhecimento do documento e qualquer outra referência que possa divulgar o documento. identidade dos autores.</p>

                <p>Somente os documentos originais devem ser enviados. Os autores são aconselhados a ler as normas éticas do INSTICC em relação ao plágio e ao autoplagismo antes de enviar e devem certificar-se de que suas submissões não se sobrepõem substancialmente ao trabalho que foi publicado em outro lugar ou simultaneamente submetido a uma revista ou a outra conferência com os procedimentos. Os documentos que contenham qualquer forma de plágio serão rejeitados sem comentários.</p>
                
                <p>Todos os documentos devem ser enviados através da plataforma de apresentação on-line PRIMORIS e devem seguir as instruções e os modelos fornecidos nos documentos aqui, que também são os modelos para a submissão da câmera. Após a apresentação do documento ter sido concluída com sucesso, os autores receberão um e-mail de confirmação automático.Todos os trabalhos apresentados no local da conferência estarão disponíveis na Biblioteca Digital SCITEPRESS. É planejado publicar uma pequena lista de versões revisadas e estendidas de artigos apresentados com Springer em um livro da Série LNAI.</p>
            
            <h3>Processo de Revisão</h3>
                <p>Todas as revisões são baseadas em envios de artigos completos (não resumos) após um processo em dupla ocultação. Todos os artigos estão sujeitos a análise de plágio usando uma ferramenta de software antes da revisão.</p>
                
                <p>Todos os trabalhos regulares são revisados ??por pelo menos dois revisores, mas geralmente por três ou mais, e avaliado considerando: Relevância, Originalidade, Qualidade Técnica, Importância e Apresentação. Os revisores também são convidados a responder um grupo de perguntas que podem ajudar os autores a melhorar o papel.</p>
                
                <p>Finalmente, os revisores podem fornecer algumas observações de texto livre que foram entregues aos autores e também algumas observações privadas de texto livre, disponibilizadas apenas para a cadeira do programa. Avaliações conflitantes podem exigir a atribuição de um novo revisor. No final, as cadeiras do programa decidem. O autor tem um período de refutação, o que desencadeia um fluxo de trabalho envolvendo as cadeiras e os revisores, se necessário. Todas as réplicas são respondidas, mas as decisões são finais.</p>
            
                <p>Os documentos de posição seguem um processo semelhante, mas os critérios utilizados para a classificação são ligeiramente diferentes, a fim de explicar a natureza desses documentos, ou seja, idéias especulativas e / ou trabalhos em andamento ainda não totalmente validados.</p>
                
            <h3>Formatos de papel de conferência, incluindo sessões e workshops especiais</h3>

                <p>Os autores podem enviar seu trabalho sob a forma de um Documento Regular, representando pesquisa completa e validada, ou como Documento de Posição, retratando trabalhos em andamento ou uma opinião discutível sobre um problema.</p>
                
            <details><summary><h4>Papéis Regulares</h4></summary>
                
                <p><b>Envio:</b> Recomenda-se que os Documentos regulares sejam submetidos a revisão com cerca de 8 a 10 páginas, com o tamanho da fonte e o formato da página apropriados, incluindo referências, tabelas, gráficos, imagens e apêndices. As inscrições com menos de 4 páginas ou mais de 13 páginas serão automaticamente rejeitadas.</p>
                
                <p><b>Aceitação:</b> Após uma revisão de pares duplo-cega, os documentos periódicos qualificados podem ser aceitos como documentos completos ou papéis curtos.</p>
                
                <p><b>Apresentação:</b> os trabalhos regulares classificados como papéis completos recebem um espaço de 30 minutos para uma apresentação oral na conferência. Os papéis regulares classificados como Papéis curtos recebem um espaço de 20 minutos para uma apresentação oral ou atribuídos a um presente em uma sessão de cartazes. Os autores que receberam uma apresentação oral, completa ou curta, podem, no entanto, optar por apresentar uma Sessão de cartaz, em vez disso, se preferirem.</p>
                
                <p><b>Publicação:</b> os documentos regulares classificados como Papéis completos receberão um limite de 12 páginas nos Procedimentos da Conferência, enquanto os Documentos regulares classificados como Papéis Curtos têm um limite de 8 páginas. Se for absolutamente necessário, os autores podem aumentar o número total de páginas por um máximo de 4 páginas extras, por uma taxa adicional. O número total de páginas a considerar é o número obtido após o papel ter sido formatado corretamente de acordo com o modelo apropriado. Os Procedimentos da Conferência serão publicados sob um número ISBN pela SCITEPRESS e incluirão versões finais de todos os documentos aceitos, ajustados para satisfazer as recomendações dos revisores. Eles serão obtidos em suporte de papel e CD-Rom, e disponibilizados para consulta on-line na Biblioteca Digital SCITEPRESS. A publicação on-line é exclusiva de artigos que foram publicados e apresentados no evento.</p>
                
                <p><b>Indexação:</b> Os procedimentos serão submetidos ao Índice de Citação de Processos da Conferência da Thomson Reuters (CPCI / ISI), INSPEC, DBLP, EI (Elsevier Engineering Village Index) e Scopus para indexação.</p></details>
                
            <details><summary><h4>Papéis Posicionados</h4></summary>
                <p><b>Apresentação:</b> os documentos de posição devem ser submetidos para revisão com cerca de 6 ou 7 páginas, com o tamanho da fonte e o formato da página apropriados, incluindo referências, tabelas, gráficos, imagens e apêndices. As inscrições com menos de 4 páginas ou mais de 9 páginas serão automaticamente rejeitadas.</p>

                <p><b>Aceitação:</b> Após uma revisão de pares duplo-cega, os Documentos de Posição qualificados serão aceitos como Documentos Curtos.</p>

                <p><b>Apresentação:</b> os papéis de posição recebem um espaço de 20 minutos para uma apresentação oral ou atribuídos a um presente em uma sessão de cartazes. Os autores que receberam uma apresentação oral podem, no entanto, optar por apresentar uma Sessão de cartaz, em vez disso, se preferirem.</p>

                <p><b>Publicação:</b> os documentos de posição receberão um limite de 8 páginas nos Procedimentos da Conferência, que incluirão versões finais de todos os documentos aceitos, ajustados para satisfazer as recomendações dos revisores. Se for absolutamente necessário, os autores podem aumentar o número total de páginas por um máximo de 4 páginas extras, por uma taxa adicional. O número total de páginas a considerar é o número obtido após o papel ter sido formatado corretamente de acordo com o modelo apropriado. Os Procedimentos da Conferência serão publicados sob um número ISBN pela SCITEPRESS, em suporte de papel e CD-ROM, e disponibilizados para consulta on-line na Biblioteca Digital SCITEPRESS. A publicação on-line é exclusiva de artigos que foram publicados e apresentados no evento.</p>

                <p><b>Indexação:</b> Os procedimentos serão submetidos ao Índice de Citação de Processos da Conferência da Thomson Reuters (CPCI / ISI), INSPEC, DBLP, EI (Elsevier Engineering Village Index) e Scopus para indexação.</p></details>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <div class="parallax2" data-parallax="scroll"  data-image-src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg">
        <h1 id="titulogaleria">Galeria</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, ao utilizar a sua solução @dvd deparei-me com um pequeno problema, a imagem da parallax apenas se ajusta depois de dar scroll ou click, não ha forma de ela se ajustar logo ao abrir o summary?!

Comment: introduzi esse script na pagina html dentro de <script> </script> mas o problema continua, a imagem apenas se ajusta depois de scroll ou click

Comment: é preciso clickar sim para abrir o summary, mas nesse click o script não atua, so no primeiro click/scroll depois de o summary abrir

Comment: eu coloquei o script no final do html , será que devo colocar no inicio?!

Comment: coloquei isto no final do html e continua igual :( `<script> $(window).on("load click scroll",function(){ $(window).resize(); });</script>`

Comment: com esse codigo a parralax ja ajusta mas quando o summary abre o texto ainda fica por cima da imagem até eu der scroll ou click, por isso ja ajudou bastante, obrigado

Comment: ficou na mesma , so da o resize no primeiro scroll/click depois do summary estar aberto, devo ter algum pedaço de codigo que entra em conflito com este

Comment: tenho mais de mil linhas de código, não quero dar tanto trabalho de analise, vou usar um pequeno truque para disfarçar, pondo os summary mais longe da parallax assim ao abrir ninguem repara no bug e ao dar scroll o bug ja desapare ;)

Comment: como já utilizei o truque e o prazo de entrega está muito proximo vou experimentar isso depois da entrega e digo-lhe no que deu